# How do I force a read to pass

Tags: c, shell, system-calls

So I am writing a simple shell. The relevant codes are posted below.

```
void sig_int_handler(int signum) { 
    if (pid == -1) // do nothing
    else kill(...);
}

signal(SIGINT, sig_int_handler);

..
while(1) {
    pid = -1;
    printf(COMMAND_PROMPT);
    input_len = read(...);

    if only enter is pressed: continue;

    // parse inputs 

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) { // Do child process operations }
    else if (pid > 0) { // Parent waits for child }
    else {..}
}
```

But now when I press ctrl+c, it properly exits the child. However, if I press ctrl+c in regular terminal, it prints out "ctrl+c" on stdout, but then it doesn't do anything. How do I force a linefeed into read so that it gives me another prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to write something like a shell here.

If so: You shouldn't have to process ^C in your shell. If you set up a new process group for the child process (using `setpgid()` and `TIOCSPGRP`), only it will receive SIGINT.

Comment: Yeah I just discovered tiocspgrp, which is helpful in controlling who access stdin and stdout. However, in some other cases I still need to force the main loop to print another command prompt, how would I do that?